# Mathematics Book on Yang-Mills Equation

Tags: reference-request, textbook-recommendation, gauge-theory

I am planning to read two papers - Atiyah-Bott's paper on Yang-Mills equations on Riemann surfaces and Hitchin's Self-Duality equations on Riemann Surface. Can someone please suggest some book where basics of Yang-Mills equations are discussed?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your background?  Have you looked at for example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110654/about-mf-atiyah-and-r-botts-1983-paper ?

Comment: Classical Theory of Gauge Fields by Rubakov: http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Theory-Fields-Valery-Rubakov/dp/0691059276/

Comment: I know basic definitions of connection and curvature of Principal Bundles. However from Hitchin's paper, it seems to me that I need some more familiarity with connection-curvature.

Comment: Th. Frankel *The Geometry of Physics*

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm erring on the side of being too elementary, but how about the notes by Michael Nielsen:

http://michaelnielsen.org/blog/yang_mills.pdf

More on the physics side, there is a highly readable book *Quantum Field Theory* by Lewis H. Ryder.